# Implementing a Model in a Relational Database

Tags: database, relational-database

I have a super-class/subclass hierarchical relationship as follows:

Super-class: IT Specialist

Sub-classes: Databases, Java, UNIX, PHP

Given that each instance of a super-class may not be a member of a subclass and a super-class instance may be a member of two or more sub-classes, how would I go about implementing this system?

I haven't been given any attributes to assign to the entities so I find this very vague and I'm at a loss where to start.

Comment: This is a faq, please google stackoverflow database subtypes.

Comment: It's been a while since you posted this question, so I'm just following up to see if you still have this problem? If you do, can you please let us know, so we can attempt to help you further. If your problem has been successfully resolved with help from an answer here, please don't forget to accept the solution by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to accept my answer (or any other answers), though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly on the site :)

Answer (score 0):

To get started, you would have one table that contains all of your super-classes (in your example case, there would only be `IT Specialist`, but it could also contain things like `Networking Specialist`, or `Digital Specialist`). I've included these to give a bit more flavour:

```
ID  | Name                  | 
-----------------------------
1   | IT Specialist         |
2   | Networking Specialist |
3   | Digital Specialist    |
```

You also would have another table that contains all of your sub-classes:

```
ID  | Name         | 
--------------------
1   | Databases    |
2   | Java         |
3   | UNIX         |
4   | PHP          |
```

For example, let's say that a `Networking Specialist` needs to know about `Databases`, and a `Digital Specialist` needs to know about both `Java` and `PHP`. An `IT Specialist` would need to know all four fields listed above.

There are two possible ways to go about this. One such way would be to set 'flags' in the sub-class table:

```
ID  | Name      | Is_IT | Is_Networking | Is_Digital
----------------------------------------------------
1   | Databases | 1     | 1             | 0
2   | Java      | 1     | 0             | 1
3   | UNIX      | 1     | 0             | 0
4   | PHP       | 1     | 0             | 1
```

Keep in mind, this is only using a small number of skills. If you started to have a *lot* of super-classes, the columns in the sub-class table could get out of hand pretty quickly.

Fortunately, you can also use something known as a **[bridging table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)** (also known as an associative entity). Essentially, a bridging table allows you to have two foreign keys that are primary keys in another table, solving the problem of a **many-to-many** relationship.

You would set this up by having a new table that **associates** which sub-classes belong with which super-classes:

```
ID  | Sub-class ID | Super-class ID |
-------------------------------------
1   | 1            | 1              |
2   | 1            | 2              |
3   | 2            | 1              |
4   | 2            | 3              |
5   | 3            | 1              |
6   | 4            | 1              |
7   | 4            | 3              |
```

Note that there are 'duplicates' in both the sub-class ID and super-class ID fields, yet no duplicates in the ID field. This is because the bridging table has unique IDs, which it uses to make independent associations. Sub-class 1 (`Databases`) needs to be associated to two different groups (`IT Specialist` and `Networking Specialist`). Thus, two different associations need to be formed.

Both approaches above give the same 'result'. The only real difference here is that a bridging table will give you more **rows**, while setting multiple flags will give you more **columns**. Obviously, the way in which you craft your query will be different as well.

Which of the two approaches you choose to go with really depends on how much data you're dealing with, and how much scope the database is going to have for expansion in the future :)

Hope this helps! :)